# Printing arabic text using Zebra printer [ZPL]

Tags: printing, zebra-printers, zpl, zpl-ii

As the title says Is there any option to print the arabic content ZPL Printer.

Thing tried is adding the font and initiate the print

```
^XA ^FX ^FR ^CF0,40^CI28^FO130,45^FH^FD محاكمة Font file^FS ^XZ
```

My printer has TT0003M_.TTF font installed but it shows  "????" when i tried to print arabic using

```
^XA^FO50,50^AE:TT0003M_.TTFN,50,50^FDمحاكمة^FS ^XZ
```

Any idea how to install a font and print the arabic text using ZPL language?

Answer (score 3):

```
^XA^CI28^CW1,E:TT0003M_.TTF^LL130^FS  
^PA0,1,1,1  
^FO50,50^A1N30,30^FDمحاكمة‏
^FS  
^XZ
```

Updated this answer to match the other question

Also found this on the Zebra KB - https://km.zebra.com/kb/index?page=content&id=SO6820&actp=RSS

Comment: I tried your code but I still have issues with displaying the arabic fonts. It shows ????

Comment: Are you sure that the font is on the system and that the font has the characters you need? You also need to be very careful that the tool or code you are using is handling unicode properly.

Comment: Yes I am sure that the font is on the printer.
**You also need to be very careful that the tool or code you are using is handling unicode properly. **
 I am using the Zebra setup utilities---Open communication with printer to test and design the label

Comment: Please see my question here where I have described in details
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45030196/utf-8-character-not-printing-with-zebra-printer

Comment: What is `^PA` ? I don't have it in my ZPL documentation.

Comment: It is in the latest ZPL manual.

Answer (score 1):

**Maybe it is too late to answer your question :) but I have the same issue and I solve it so I want to share my answer.**

---

> 1- You can use [**ZebraDesigner 3**](https://www.zebra.com/us/en/products/software/barcode-printers/zebralink/zebra-designer.html) or "**BarTender Designer**" to design your ZPL code.
>
> 2- Use this font [**ZEBRA Swiss Unicode**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qcsZ6.png), it support Arabic characters.
>
> 3- After finish your design click **Print** and check the box "**Print to file**" then click Print and save the file with extension "**.prn**".[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sjfym.png)
>
> 4- Open the file using **notepad** and you will see the **ZPL** code.
>
> 5- Here is the result

```
^FPH,3^FT225,224^A@N,141,141,TT0003M_^FH\^CI28^FDمحاكمة^FS^CI27
```

Or the full result in this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A0bu6.png).

> 6- If you are using online zpl viewer like [this](http://labelary.com/viewer.html) don't worry if you can't see the Arabic characters, but if you want to print you will not see any problems
>
> 7- **Don't** try to make your text in the center ,usin this will cut and reverse the Arabic text

- The default is **Field Text** > "**^FT**"or with x,x"**^FTx,y**" "**^FT225,224**" like in this code:

  ^FPH,3^FT225,224^A@N,141,141,TT0003M_^FH\^CI28^FDمحاكمة^FS^CI27
- If you try to center,right or left your Arabic text it will use **Field Block** "**^FB**" "^FB383,1,75,C" it is different than "^FT" and it is not supporting Arabic text.

  ^FPH,3^FT225,224^A@N,141,141,TT0003M_^FB383,1,75,C^FH\^CI28^FDمحاكمة^FS^CI27
- you can see Field Block properties in this [book](https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra/manuals/printers/common/programming/zpl-zbi2-pm-en.pdf) at page **169**

> 8- I'm not sure but I tried very hard and there is no way to center the arabic text until now.
>
> - **But I have a trick using ^FT width to calculate the center**

Using this function ,it is **c#**:

```
//Define page_width and font_width 

int page_width = 600;
int font_width = 18;
```

call the function it will return **X** position (center).

```
string ar = "محاكمة محاكمة محاكمة";

string FT_center = center_line(ar);
```

here is the function, 315 = middle width or center point

```
public string center_line(string arabic_text)

    {

        int text_width = (arabic_text.Length * font_width) / 2;
        decimal d = ((page_width - (text_width / 2)));
        int x = Convert.ToInt16(Math.Round(d)) ;
        x = 315 + (text_width / 2);
        return x.ToString();

    }
```

use it like this:

```
^FPH,3^FT"+FT_center+@",224^A@N,141,141,TT0003M_^FH\^CI28^FDمحاكمة^FS^CI27
```

Answer (score 0):

use this to print Arabic chars

```
^FT39,495^A@N,24,25,TT0003M_^FH\^CI28^FDالعربية لغةٌ رسمية في كل دول الوطن العربي إضافة إلى كونها لغة رسمية^FS^CI27
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).