# Printing in Arabic on a Bluetooth printer

Tags: android-studio

I use Bluetooth printer but don't support Arabic
I tried many methods and also used UTF-8, but don't work
Is there a way to show the Arabic language in print?

```
    String msg =  "مرحبا";
                //msg= URLEncoder.encode(msg,"UTF-8");
                //StandardCharsets.UTF_8
                //"UTF-8"
                outputStream.write(msg.getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

Comment: Not all fonts will have all the unicode populated, you may need to select the correct font first, but sending UTF-8 should be the right format to send https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26715741/printing-arabic-text-using-zebra-printer-zpl

You should describe what happens when you try. What goes wrong?

Comment: When the code Run, the printer print ?????